# How do I use a PDF form as a template?

Tags: pdf, template

We're using SPO and have several PDF forms that we'd like to use as templates. Currently, after I've added it to the template list and select it, the form doesn't open. However, there is a new form created in the library.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of "**PDF Share Forms Cloud**" form as a template and using this form template users can submit the data.  In order to do this we need to follow the below steps:

1. Go to Add an app page from your site content page.
2. Then we will get the below page - then search with **"PDF Share Forms Cloud"** as mentioned below (1), then click on the second link highlighted as 2 link.
   [image]
3. Then we will land into the below page:
   https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_layouts/15/storefront.aspx?source=%2Fsites%2FSharePointRND&sname=SharePoint%20RND#qry=PDF%20Forms%20for%20Office%20365

[image]

4. Click on the **"PDF Share Forms Cloud"** app
5. In the next screen we can add this app.
   [image]

**Notes:**

- The account using which adding this app should be tenant administrator otherwise we will get this error: **Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app.**
- This form can be customized/designed as per our needs.
- We can take an interactive PDF form and make it a template. Publish it as a Content Type in Document Library and let other users fill in forms based on this template.

**Customized form template example:**

Here in the left panel, we can see that all traditional controls are available for form designing.

[image]

**PDF form template has been used as content type for re-usability**

[image]